# Microsoft Access - Include Last Modified By

Tags: ms-access

I'm setting up a Data Update Form for my Access table for records to be updated. I just included a Last modified Date and Time fields, however, I was wondering was there anyway I could capture the user who was doing the update? Thanks

Comment: You can use ^ this function e.g. as default value for the username field.

Comment: You can't use a user-defined function for a Table's Field DefaultValue property - however if you're populating the table using a Form - as in Add Mode - you can set the DefaultValue property of the control to be your function. Something like `Environ$("Username")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do this, i typically keep a variable in the event in the 'save changes' button.  This variable is set to 'Environ(Username)' upon clicking, or 'CurrentUser' (if you are using mdb and are using Access Security methods).  You can also keep a method in the 'BeforeChanges' event of the form your editing, and send this information to an Audit Log table as well.